# How to Wait in Selenium WebDriver when WebDriverWait or Implicit Wait Won't Do

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and I'm facing the following issue:

Basically, there's a popup on a page that appears after clicking button on page. I want to dismiss the popup. To do so, I'm clicking on the x icon on top right corner. I'm able to identify the element correctly and click on it using XPath (I know XPath is correct because it works in Firebug and Selenium does not throw any exception when using the XPath so the element must be present. Additionally, both `isDisplayed()` and `isEnabled()` return true). The funny thing is that the popup does not disappear after doing this. However, if I add a 3 second delay (before dismissing popup) the popup disappears. My issue is that I don't want to delay execution of program more than necessary so I'd rather use a max delay of 3-5 seconds but if the popup is ready to be interacted with (i.e, dismissed) I want to dismiss it as soon as possible.

I thought of using something like:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But this does not work bec as stated the driver detects the web element as being present (and visible and displayed) immediately but click won't work unless I wait 3 seconds.

Similarly, I cannot use:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30, 5000);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

for the same reason (this would only work if the said element was not clickable/visible before 3 seconds but as far as `WebDriver` is concerned - it's visible right away)

Can someone help me understand why despite the fact element is present the click is not being successful and how can I make it so that Selenium clicks as soon as the click will succeed without waiting full 3-5 seconds.

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="a-popover-wrapper">
    <div class="a-popover-header">
    <button class=" a-button-close a-declarative" aria-label="Close" data-action="a-popover-close">
    <i class="a-icon a-icon-close"/>
    </button>
    <h4 id="a-popover-header-7" class="a-popover-header-content">Buy professional installation</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="a-popover-content-7" class="a-popover-inner pdp-service-modal-instance" style="height: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
    </div>
    <span class="a-popover-end a-popover-a11y-offscreen" tabindex="0"/>
  </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, you say the element is present, but is it disabled? If it is disabled until the popup is actually shown, then it would not be clickable. The 3 second delay could just happen to be long enough for it to be enabled.

Comment: It is enabled (`isEnabled()` returns true ) - I've updated the question with this information. Thanks.

Comment: bit hacky but have you tried to click it twice? I've seen instances where one click just doesn't quite cut the mustard.

Comment: @SimonN I did not try it but my gut feeling is that if it works, it's only working because the additional click adds a minuscule delay between first and second click so for the same price I could just add equivalent delay directly. But this is precisely what I'm trying to avoid doing.. I want something that will wait exactly as much time as necessary and not more.

Comment: @S.O.S The explicit wait in your second snippet would wait for a max time of 30 sec with the `poll_frequency` (sleep interval between calls) of 5000ms (5sec). The **default value** of the `poll_frequency` arg is 0.5s. Perhaps leaving the `poll_frequency` with its default value would help you reduce the unwanted delay in your script. Lemme know if this helps

Comment: @S.O.S Okay, Can we see the code trial along with the relevant _HTML_ please?

Comment: Please provide HTML.

Comment: @DebanjanB  HTML added.

Comment: @S.O.S The issue is in identifying **element**. Nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using **FluentWait**?
Try the below code,

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(pDriver).withTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(600,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("selector"));
```

You can use the above case or the below one,

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("selector")));
```

For further reference about **FluentWait**, Please refer this link https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait

Comment: I tried this suggestion right now - and it doesn't work (likely for the same reason WebDriverWait and implicit wait doesn't work - as stated in the question WebDriver is immediately detecting presence of element) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss Popup, Instead of using manual close icon. You can directly handle it by driver, Without waiting for Explicit wait.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: This does not work as it is not real alert please see HTML in updated question.